# D2PAK - Cooler on top?

Tags: mosfet

I have some MOSFETs with D2PAK and I would like to add a external cooler. The thing is, I can only connect the cooler on top of the D2PAK case and I think that is not so efficient anymore. There are such solder cooler for the D2PAK, but this won't work in my case, since I would like to connect the cooler to the case, where the PCB is mounted to.

So, will a large cooler on top of the D2PAK drastically reduce the heat resistance and if not, what else can be done? I had a SO-08 package in a previous project, but here is the problem, that I cannot place the decoupling caps near the FETs, since the SO-08 is not high enough, such that I cannot place a cooler without touching the decoupling caps.

Comment: Just some food for thought: https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/about-infineon/press/market-news/2018/INFPMM201806-057.html Infineon has a few packages with top side cooling. Essentially a electrically insulating, thermally conductive ceramic plate instead of the top side plastic. Not sure of your application/circuit, so I just linked an article they posted back in 2018 about it. I've had some success with their TOLT packages (leadless and top cooled) but I try to stay away from them. Might be worth a look though.

Comment: How much power do you need to dissipate?

Answer (score 2):

> So, will a large cooler on top of the D2PAK drastically reduce the heat resistance

Not much.

The problem is that the thermal resistance from the actual thing that gets hot to the plastic casing is really high, compared to the metal on the bottom. The MOSFET datasheet usually specifies these! It's an important parameter. Heat is typically *the* limiting factor.

So, no deal. You need to thermally connect the MOSFET bottom to your case. It's probably better to just solder the MOSFET to the PCB and give the PCB a large plated hole to solder in a piece of copper to connect to the case than to just put something on top. (you can of course do both.)

Maybe having a shaped piece of copper:

```
---    ---
  |    |
  |====|
  ------
```

to screw to the case on top, and to screw to the MOSFET's (`====`) bottom on the other side works too for you.

Comment: They make heatsinks intended for surface-mount parts that solder onto the same large copper pad as the part's thermal tab, but I don't know how effective they are. They kinda arch over the part and then have extra fins on the sides, see [https://www.boydcorp.com/aavid-datasheets/Board-Level-Cooling-Surface-Mount-5731.pdf](this datasheet) for instance. There are even some big finned extruded ones, which I was surprised to learn.

Comment: @Hearth That link got mangled: [Board Level Cooling – Surface Mount 5731](https://www.boydcorp.com/aavid-datasheets/Board-Level-Cooling-Surface-Mount-5731.pdf)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Oops, don't know what happened there. Thank you.